# Get name of clicked rectangle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to get the name of a clicked Rectangle in my WPF application. 
I tried first this:
XAML:

```
<Canvas Width="1680" Height="800" MouseLeftButtonDown="canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">
```

XAML.cs

```
private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedRect;
    if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
    {
        Rectangle ClickedRectangle = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource;

        var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;
        selectedRect = elementName.ToString();
    }
}
```

It works well, but then I don't know how to pass the selectedRect string to my ViewModel
So I tried to pass directly the Relay command from xaml to Viewmodel:

```
<UserControl  x:Class="G.View.MapView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
      xmlns:extended="clr-namespace:G.ViewModel">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height=".2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,0,0">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CaskList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="1680" Height="800">
                            <Canvas.InputBindings>
                                <!-- One type of implementation -->
                                <KeyBinding Key="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDown.GestureKey}" Command="{Binding Path=HandleMyEvent}"/>
                            </Canvas.InputBindings>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Width="64" Height="64" Fill="{Binding Color}"></Rectangle>
                            <Label Content="{Binding ID}" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>      
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

It works, I enter correctly in my method when I click the canvas, but I can not get the rectangle name, not having the event MouseButtonEventArgs e.
Can you help me?

EDIT: added complete xaml

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedRect;
    if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
    {
        Rectangle ClickedRectangle = (Rectangle)e.OriginalSource;

        var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;
        selectedRect = elementName.ToString();

        //ViewModel code
        var vm = this.ViewModel as YourViewModel;
        vm.RectangleName = elementName.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get an error : my xaml.cs does not contain a definition for 'ViewModel'

Comment: Well try to get the view model from your first element in the xaml that has view model (grid or user control). If you don't know how to find it, post here your xaml

Comment: I added the complete xaml in my original question. And in my code I added
        var vm = this.ViewModel as YourViewModel;
        vm.RectangleName = elementName.ToString();
in xaml.cs, but I get the error: my xaml.cs does not contain a definition for 'ViewModel'